# Differentiate look of Radiofield and Checkbox field in Sencha Touch 1.1

Tags: sencha-touch

By default, Sencha Touch 1.1 provides a `radiofield` and a `checkboxfield` which show a check mark (tick).  Because of this design, there is no visual way to differentiate between them.

[image: Sencha Touch radiofield]

How can I change the look of the `radiofield` so that it looks like a traditional radio button?

Answer (score 2):

I added my own styles to change the look of the checkbox.

```
.x-field .x-input-radio:after, .x-field .x-input-radio:checked:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 1.25em;
    height: 1.25em;
    top: 50%;
    left: auto;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skew(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
    right: 1.1em;
    border: .45em solid;
    margin-top: -0.75em;
}
.x-field .x-input-radio:checked:after {
    border-color: #06346a;
}
.x-field .x-input-radio:after {
    border-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: I tried this out, and it looks mostly the same. For the bounty, can you show how I can style it to look like a normal radio button?

Comment: @TravisWebb - I spent a bit of time trying to do that but I'm not the greatest with CSS3 so I stayed with the above style.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
.x-field .x-input-radio:after,
.x-field.x-item-disabled .x-input-radio:checked:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 1.4em;
    height: 1.4em;
    top: 50%;
    left: auto;
    right: 1.1em;
    -webkit-mask-image: url();
    margin-top: -0.7em;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.x-field .x-input-radio:checked:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: auto;
    right: 1.1em;
    -webkit-mask-image: url();
    margin-top: -0.7em;
    border: 5px solid #dddddd;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Link: http://tjwebb.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/how-to-override-the-default-sencha-touch-2-radio-field-style/